# How to set up a VPN gateway box with limited port availability

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, openvpn, tor

I have full root access on a Ubuntu virtual server. I have OpenVPN up and running, and it's working fine for me tunnelling my devices' internet traffic when travelling abroad to ensure clean and unrestricted Internet access.

Now, I would like to add the option of additionally using TOR which would be set up on the gateway. However, I would also like to fall back to regular masquerading only.

What are my options? Obviously, I might set up another OpenVPN process listening an another port and whose forwarded traffic might be routed through TOR. However, I don't want to use another config setup. It would be great to aolve this issue without a different config.

Is it possible to set up an optional proxy server for this? How would I set up a mobile device (Android-powered) to use a (server-side) proxy server after creating the OpenVPN tunnel beforehand? Or am I missing some other option here?

Comment: Why run tor on the server? Just run it on your local machine. That should also make it go faster...

Comment: Doesn't running TOR on a VPN client greatly increaae traffic overhead, since all those connections TOR creates, maintains and destroys must now be tunneled as well?

Comment: Fair enough, but do you really need to run tor through the VPN tunnel? Tor is supposed to anonymise your traffic, you really don't need to tunnel it anywhere...